# Error while trying to uninstall pip ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, vim, pip, apt

This is literally driving me crazy.

There are dozens of threads with the same kind of error but I couldn't find anything that works in my case.
So here's what happens, when I'm trying to either launch pip, uninstall pip, install -f pip with apt, install pip with get-pip.py or launch vi(m) (wtf?):

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

I tried to force uninstall pip, nothing.
I tried to void PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME, nothing.

I don't know where this site module is but I will look for it, I will find it and I will kill it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, it seems that you messed up your python installation. I would consider reinstalling python via `apt-get`. If that does not help, please edit `which -a pip` in your question.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7 returns the same error.
... But python launches fine

Comment: did you screw around with the system python?

Comment: Definetly, I was trying to install python 2.7.9 and at some point I did sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/ and sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/

I'm a little bit ashamed of it, I stupidly followed a tuto saying the python 2.7.9 install would replace the deleted files...

Comment: In fact now I'd just like to install Python 2.7 again without having to reset everything. `sudo apt-get install python2.7` doesn't work complaining with missing files.

Comment: Well messing with system python was really a bad idea. You better not delete any files that require `sudo` permissions, unless you know exactly what you are doing. That said, I would suggest having a look at this thread at askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187227/i-run-sudo-apt-get-remove-python2-7-can-i-restore-my-ubuntu-now
This requires some effort, but it seems that there is a fix that does not require reinstalling.

Comment: Hmm... Couldn't find what I was looking for so I planned to do this : install the same version of Ubuntu on a separate partition and then copy the python files. When I ran the installer though, it seduced me with the idea of upgrading Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS to 14.10. Solved the issue without any loss, pfieuw. Thanks for the support though guys!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I got around the issue upgrading my system from Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS to 14.10 with a live USB.

It's not really solving the issue, but it re-installed Python properly so that's good for me.
Thanks for the support.